# PHP PDO Group results by column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it possible to group results by a column using PDO?

I'm currently using the following code to get data from MySQL:

```
<?php
// connect (better to be moved into included file)
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$db = new PDO($dsn,"xxxxx", "xxxxx", $opt);

// getting files
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM releases");
$files = $stmt->fetchAll();

//output
?>
<div id="contentWrapper">
<?php foreach($files as $row): ?>
<div id='contentItem'>
    <a href="<?=$row['fullURL']?>" title="<?=$row['title']?>">
        <img src="<?=$row['imgURL']?>" width='200px' height='150px' />
    </a>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

I want to group the results by the release_date column in my database like so:

```
RELEASE DATE 1
 - product 1
 - product 2
RELEASE DATE 2
 - product 3
...
```

I can get the desired results using the following code, although I can't seem to get it working with PDO rather than standard MySQL connection.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM releases");
$group_date = null;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
if ($group_date !== substr($row["release_date"], 0, 10)) {
    $group_date = substr($row["release_date"], 0, 10);
```

Comment: Since you're doing it in the application by testing `$group_date`, the same principle should apply to both. Is your PDO display code different?

Comment: @tadman I thought it'd be the same but I'm not sure where to place the `$group_date` code into my initial PDO selection. I assumed this would replace `$files = $stmt->fetchAll();` but it errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've the following code *right after* you load the next row from resultset into the `$row` variable:

```
if ($group_date !== substr($row["release_date"], 0, 10)) {
    $group_date = substr($row["release_date"], 0, 10);
```

you'll put it at the same location in the code using PDO:

```
<?php
foreach($files as $row):
if ($group_date !== substr($row["release_date"], 0, 10)) {
    $group_date = substr($row["release_date"], 0, 10);
?>
```

---

You can optimize performance by not loading the entire resultset into an array by doing:

```
<?php ...
....
// $files = $stmt->fetchAll();
// See that I've commented it here
// as you don't call fetchAll now
$group_date = "";
?>
<div id="contentWrapper">
<?php
while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
// Notice the change above
if ($group_date !== substr($row["release_date"], 0, 10)) {
    $group_date = substr($row["release_date"], 0, 10);
?>
<div id='contentItem'>
    <a href="<?=$row['fullURL']?>" title="<?=$row['title']?>">
        <img src="<?=$row['imgURL']?>" width='200px' height='150px' />
    </a>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I've tried your optimized code but I still can't get it working. I thought it may be because the `$group_date = null;` was missing, but adding that in didn't fix it either. I'm just getting a blank page, whereas my original PDO code returns results.

Comment: @jacobgibbs You'd need to replace `endforeach` with the closing curly bracket `}`. See the edits above

Comment: @jacobgibbs Depends on how you were closing the `if` statement in your non-PDO code

Comment: my mistake, i'd wanted to display the group date. Your code works fine for me when I add `...<div id='contentItem'>
<p><?=$group_date;?></p>
<?php } ?>...`